# Starting gif image when i scroll on the website

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, gif

I want to start a Gif image when i scroll.
Please can you have a solution? This is my code in Wordpress :

http://www.pier17.fr/test

```
<img class="gif-load" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/nos-services-title.gif" />
```

Thank you so much in advance :)

Comment: Have two images, make the first one only have one frame and use that as src. Use javascript to detect scroll and then change the src.

Comment: I'm not understand, can you explain me in detail Stephan please? :s Sorry for disturb you but i'm really lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take two images one is png and another one is gif.

Initially the img tag src will be normal.png or empty,when the user scroll up or down just set img src to gif image.Use jquery.mousewheel.js plugin for mousewheel (all browsers).Intially load the gif image when page is loading.load gif image like this.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      if(document.images){
        img1 = new Image();
        img1.src = "images/image.gif";
      }
   </script>

  // for mouse wheel functionality

    $(document).on('mousewheel', function() {
        if (eventt.deltaY == -1) {
           //user scolls down 
          $('img .gif-load').attr('src','gif-image-path');
        }
        if (eventt.deltaY == 1) {
             //user scolls up
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: No need for a plugin, just use object.addEventListener('scroll', function);

Comment: Ok thank you so much DIleep,

I have this image to display when i scroll : nos-references-title.gif
In this code where i make it in the code? and where i make the other image white-img/jpg (image display before scroll)?

Thanks a lot

Comment: before scroll <img class="gif-load" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/white-img.jpg" />;

Comment: after scroll you can change img src to gif image src